# Traversing matrix values in diagonal "zig-zags"

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, matrix, indexing

I have a matrix with a defined size of n x n. The at each index of the matrix grid, there is an integer value. The grid is created by wrapping the integers every nth value. See below for a 4x4 example, created from the string input "**6 4 7 5 3 8 9 2 1 5 1 7 1 6 2 8**":

[image: 4x4 Matrix]

I want to traverse the grid such that only the values that are diagonally left and/or right are printed, and then from the newfound value(s), their diagonals.

[image: 4x4 Matrix w/ Route]

Some example routes for the example grid (one marked * shown above):

```
index[0][0]: [6,8,1,6], [6,8,1,6], [6,8,1,8]

index[0][1]: [4,3,5,1], [4,3,5,2], [4,9,5,2], [4,9,5,1], [4,9,7,2] *
```

where the route would be outputted as:

```
4351, 4352, 4952 etc.
```

Essentially, I would like to find all the routes in a 'zig-zag' fashion within the grid.

My current code is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        int s = 4; //For demo purposes
        int k = 0;
        

        String grid[][] = new String[s][s]; //Grid will always be n x n
        
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); //Handles a whitespace delimited string
        String[] in = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");


        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Creates the grid
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
                        grid[i][j] = in[k];
                        k++;
                }
        }
        
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) { //Route finder
                for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { 
                    //find a diagonal value and append the value to the route
                }
                //Print the route integers for this specific route
        }
}
```

How would I go about finding these routes within the matrix? And also work around almighty *IndexOutOfBounds* errors?

Comment: If you `return` within a loop, you won't get the chance to find any alternate routes.

Comment: @ScottHunter edited code snippet to read print instead.

Comment: @ScottHunter I had bounds checkers within the second loop but omitted them as to allow for any ideas from other users to work around it. The loop itself does not give bound errors, but checking to see if the diagonal values does. Doing `grid[i+1][j+1]` and `grid[i+1][j-1]` gives errors directly on running since the latter tries to check a -1 index column. _This_ is the IndexOutOfBounds errors I am referring to. Apologies if this was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a RECURSIVE solution:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int k = 0;
    int size = 4; // For demo purposes

    String grid[][] = new String[size][size]; //Grid will always be n x n
    String[] in = "6 4 7 5 3 8 9 2 1 5 1 7 1 6 2 8".split("\\s+"); // For demo purposes

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) { //Creates the grid
      for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        grid[i][j] = in[k];
        k++;
      }
    }

    ArrayList<String> paths = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(int c = 0; c < size; c++) {
      // start at each column in the first row
      findPaths(0, c, grid, "", paths);
    }

    // output the paths found
    // *note that for the demo grid, there are "duplicate paths" taking different physical routes in the grid
    for(String path : paths) {
      System.out.println(path);
    }
  }    

  public static void findPaths(int row, int col, String[][] grid, String currentPath, ArrayList<String> paths) {
    // are we within the grid?
    if ((row >=0) && (row < grid.length) && (col >= 0) && (col < grid[row].length)) {
      currentPath = currentPath + grid[row][col];

      // did we hit the bottom?
      if (row == (grid.length - 1)) {
        paths.add(currentPath);
      } 
      else {
        // go left
        findPaths(row+1, col-1, grid, currentPath, paths);
        // go right
        findPaths(row+1, col+1, grid, currentPath, paths);
      } 
    }
  }
```

Producing:

```
6816
6816
6818
4351
4352
4951
4952
4972
7816
7816
7818
7216
7218
5951
5952
5972
```

Comment: Appreciate the solution! Will take a look at it later today and see if I run into any issues on my end.

Comment: Update: works great! Interacts with scanner a bit weirdly, the string takes a long time to write to the grid when it is input by the user. No issues when the string is within the code however.

Comment: Glad to hear it works well.  Not sure why it would be slower when using the Scanner...would have to take a look at your new code.

Comment: `Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`
`String[] in =  sc.nextLine().split("\\s+");`

Ideally the program would read multiple lines of input (with each row of values corresponding to one line) but I am working on a solution for that.